# Display Facebook photos on website

Tags: php, facebook, photos

There are topics about statuses, walls and profiles, but none about photos...

What I'm trying to achieve is to display the photos of my page/profile/etc. onto my website. I stumbled upon [an FQL method](http://www.codeofaninja.com/2011/06/display-facebook-photos-to-your-website.html) in combination with Lightbox. It seems to do everything I need, except for some reason the FaceBook API isn't connecting with Facebook. This array remains empty.

```
$fql = "SELECT aid, cover_pid, name FROM album WHERE owner=11239244970";
   $param  =   array(
     'method'    => 'fql.query',
     'query'     => $fql,
     'callback'  => ''
   );
$fqlResult   =   $facebook->api($param);
```

Are there other alternatives or any tips/hints you can give?

Comment: It works perfectly, `Array ( [0] => Array ( [aid] => 11239244970_37770 [cover_pid] => 11239244970_294796 [name] => Profile Pictures ) )`

Comment: Hm... What do you do? :s

Comment: Just copied your code and tried to use print_r($fqlResult)

Comment: Oké, I see! I must be located somewhere in the `permissions` of Facebook I think. Because with this ownerID, I see pictures too. So I guess my page was protected in some way!

Comment: yeah, you need permissions for closed albums. This one is open

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't forget that you need `user_photos` permission to access your own non-public albums, otherwise you'll just get an empty array as you're describing. Read [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/) for more details

Answer (score 0):

There is a super easy alternative of displaying photos from your facebook profile.  It involves using an iframe code generated from [facebookgalleria.com](http://facebookgalleria.com) that looks something like this:

```
<iframe src="http://facebookgalleria.com/gallery.php?id=nike&rows=4&margin=10&cols=3&width=170&font_size=11&title_color=000&hide_next_back=0&share_buttons=1&shape=rectangle&frame=1" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" frameborder="0" width="551" style="height: 769px;" ></iframe>
```

This code is used for display photos from a facebook PAGE but if you want to display facebook photos from your personal profile, you have to facebookgalleria.com, connect with facebook and then generate your iframe code.  The code automatically pulls new photos from your albums every 2-3 hours.  Good luck!